# How to convert string to date using Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and trying to convert my added columns into a formatted Date.

I added this code to Convert but it's not working : `= pd.to_datetime(df1['RawMonth'],RD_DateFormat)`  , `= pd.to_datetime(df1['RawMonth'],CRD_DateFormat)`.

Below is my Script

```
RD_DateFormat = '%m-%b-%y'
CRD_DateFormat = '%m-%b'

for excel_file in excel_files:
   sheet = os.path.basename(excel_file)
   sheet = sheet.split("_")[1]
   sheet = sheet.split(".")[0] 
   RDate = datetime.strptime(sheet, RD_DateFormat) 
   df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

df1.insert(loc=len(df1.columns), column='RMonth', value=RDate)  = 
pd.to_datetime(df1['RMonth'],RD_DateFormat)

df1.insert(loc=len(df1.columns), column='CRDDate', value=RDate) = 
pd.to_datetime(df1['RMonth'],CRD_DateFormat)
```

Expected output display in Excel

```
RMonth     |  CRDMonth
01-SEP-20  |  SEP-01
02-SEP-20  |  SEP-02
05-SEP-20  |  SEP-05
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the keyword argument name as well:

```
pd.to_datetime(df1['RawMonth'], format=RD_DateFormat)
pd.to_datetime(df1['RawMonth'], format=CRD_DateFormat)
```